# Why is this shown as "Modified" when I don't see anything there?

Tags: support, specific-answer, deleted-answers

The question [Gameboy emulator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204311/gameboy-emulator-in-c) is showing up on the *Top Questions* as "Modified 6 hours ago by Sami 1".

Clicking on the "modified" word takes me to the question itself, not a comment or answer.  The only two posts here (Q and one A) have no recent edits.  No new comments either.  The user Sami is new with *no activity* on his profile page.  So what is he supposed to have changed that doesn't show up on his activity summary or the "modified" thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sami posted [an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/269226) around 6 hours ago. However the answer was subsequently deleted. Deleting answers doesn't remove the question from being bumped to the front page.

When you get [10k](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) you'll be able to see deleted answers.